# Ping through a specific Ethernet port

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, socket

I am using RHEL 6.4, I have teamed two Ethernet ports (eth2 and eth3). I am trying to test the connectivity, I mean I want to test whether the eth2 and eth3 are working or not?

One way is to disable one port (each at a time) and do ping, but I don't want to take a risk of losing connection if this is a single point of failure.

So I want to know if there's a way to ping to other servers through a specific port, 
Something like #ping 10.0.0.5 via eth2 (to test eth2 connectivity)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the fine manual for `ping(8)`

```
   -I interface address
          Set  source address to specified interface address. Argument may
          be numeric IP address or name of device. When pinging IPv6 link-
          local address this option is required.
```

Comment: I found that we can also use "#ethtool -S eth2" option. but need more clarification.